# no such file or directory: .dbt

Tags: macos, pip, homebrew, miniconda, dbt

I created a virtual environent using anaconda. When I check the version inside my environment using

```
pip3 —version
```

it is Python 3.10.6.

Then I installed dbt like this:

```
pip3 install dbt-snowflake
```

While doing so, I was in my home directory.

However, now when I try to access the profiles or dbt folder, I am unable to do so.

```
(env-name) username@XI688 ~ % cd .dbt

(env-name) username@XI688 ~ % cd ~/.dbt/
(env-name) username@XI688 ~ % cd ~/.dbt
```

However, I keep getting errors:

```
cd: no such file or directory: /Users/username/.dbt/
```

Meanwhile, if I check the

```
dbt —version
```

I get this

```
Core:
  - installed: 1.2.1
  - latest:    1.2.1 - Up to date!

Plugins:
  - snowflake: 1.2.0 - Up to date!
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I access the dbt folder?

I also tried the same commands without a virtual environment but the results were the same. Also tried installing dbt with brew.

Comment: Manually create .dbt folder if it does not already exist. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76178930/dbt-not-found-dbt-folder-on-default-default-location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `dbt init` to create `~/.dbt/profiles.yml`, as well as your dbt project folder, which will contain the code for your data transformations.

[Docs are here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/init)