# Dbt: not found .dbt folder on default default location

Tags: python, database, installation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I was creating my dbt project, but when running the command `dbt init <name_project>` it returned the error that it can't find `profiles.yml` in the `.dbt` folder. So I try to access the folder on default location and it's not there. Is there a problem install dbt-snowflake inside a python virtual env that changes the installation default behavior?

1. Created virtuaenv:
   `python3 -m venv venv`
2. Actvated venv:
   `source venv/bin/activate`
3. Updated pip:
   `pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools`
4. Install dbt-snowflake:
   `pip install dbt-snowflake`
5. Trying create a project:
   `bt init <name_project>`
   But I receive this error message:

```
Usage: dbt init [OPTIONS] [PROJECT_NAME]
Try 'dbt init -h' for help.
Error: Invalid value for '--profiles-dir': Path '/Users/brunofonseca/.dbt' does not exist.
```

I saw the default location is `~/.dbt`, so I tried to access the folder but it is not exist there. I also tried run the command `dbt debug --config-dir` to find where is the folder, but returns:

```
04:40:15  Running with dbt=1.5.0
04:40:15  [OpenCommand]: Unable to parse dict {'open_cmd': 'open', 'profiles_dir': PosixPath('/Users/brunofonseca/.dbt')}
04:40:15  To view your profiles.yml file, run:
```

Finally. I tried to find the `profiles.yml` inside the `venv` folder, but it was not found.
OBS: the operation system is macos.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to create the `.dbt` folder in your home directory beforehand, then run the `dbt init <name_project>` that will automatically create a `profiles.yml` in your `.dbt` file.